# iMessage Extension - insert text without new line

Tags: ios, swift, imessage-extension

I'm currently playing around with iMessage Extensions and had a quick question that I wondered if someone could help solve.

I'm using

```
conversation?.insertText("world", completionHandler: { error in
})
```

and this successfully inserts text into the message field, but it always enters a new line.

For instance if I already had "Hello " typed out as a message it would display

`Hello
world`

is there a way I can have "world" appear after it rather than on a new line? Similarly, if the text cursor was after "Hell" it would read "Hellworldo"

Or does insert text always create a new line? Is there anyway to get the currently typed text within the compose field?